# can swf file initialize itself for javascript with `ExternalInterface.call()` function?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

in my code there's initialization function

html

```
<embed id="SoundsObj"........
```

js

```
var SoundsObj = document.getElementById('SoundsObj');

function GetSoundsObj(){
alert(top.SoundsObj.SndPlay); //I can see it has initialized itself
}
```

as3

```
ExternalInterface.call("GetSoundsObj");
```

I'm curious is there a possibility that I can pass swf object in JS as the second argument in `ExternalInterface.call()` sunction?

something like

in as3

```
    ExternalInterface.call("GetSoundsObj",this); //by `this` I mean swf object
```

in js

```
var SoundsObj = null;

function GetSoundsObj(arg){
SoundsObj = arg;
alert(SoundsObj.SndPlay);
}
```

to be completely sure that swf-js bridge is on?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [`objectID`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#objectID):

```
ExternalInterface.call("GetSoundsObj", ExternalInterface.objectID);
```

JS:

```
var SoundsObj = null;

function GetSoundsObj(swfId){
    SoundsObj = document.getElementById(swfId);
    alert(SoundsObj.SndPlay);
}
```

Note that you should set the `name` attribute on the `<embed>` tag as well as the `id`, or just use the `<object>` tag.